# How to upload an array of files to a web-server from an application?

Tags: c#, forms, file, post

Using c#, I have a method which uploads a file using a `POST` HTTP method. But the server is expecting an array of files. So what should I change, or more generally, how can I `POST` an array or list of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery and an upload plugin like the one here:

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I mean loading from application like windows forms or console application

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142804/post-multiple-files-and-form-values-using-net-console-application