# checking, is user authenticated in mvc application, when local applications sends requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, request

I have asp .net mvc application with authorization system. Console(or winforms, doesn't matter) application uses WebRequest to post some data to server. Everything is ok, but know I need check, is user authorized, and return it. So, I'm cheking

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

and it returns false. But in browser I'm authenticated and this method obviosly works in mvc-aplication, but when console application sends requests, it doesn't work. How to solve it?

I'm using [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142804/post-multiple-files-and-form-values-using-net-console-application) to load my files

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your console application needs to also send the "forms authentication cookie or ticket" in the request to your web server. This post might be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187198/Various-Clients-and-Forms-Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your web request (I assume you mean an `HttpWebRequest`), make sure it's configured to send windows credentials.

For `HttpWebRequest`, you would set [`UseDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) to `true`:

> Set this property to true when requests made by this [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) object should, if requested by the server, be authenticated using the credentials of the currently logged on user.

Comment: It doesn't work( I tried to make simple request to page, that writes just is user authenticated, but it returns false even if I set UseDefaultCredentials true..

Comment: I thing I have some server problem, because when I request vk.com it is authorized even without UseDefaultCredentials